# Java code using HashSet of longs doesn't work?

Tags: java, long-integer, hashset

This simple Java code adds `2` to a set of `long`, and subsequently prints whether `2` is a member of the set:

```
import java.util.*;

class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Long> s = new HashSet<Long>();
        long x = 2;
        s.add(x);
        System.out.println(s.contains(2));
    }
}
```

It should print `true` since `2` is in the set, but instead it prints `false`. Why?

```
$ javac A.java && java A
false
```

Comment: Try using a `Long` object instead of a `long` primitive.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - A `long` primitive would have worked fine because of autoboxing. The problem is that it was an `int` primitive.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The literal 2 was treated as `int` thus autoboxed to `Integer`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your set contains instances of `Long` and you were looking for an `Integer` (the type into which an `int` is boxed when an `Object` is required).

Test

```
System.out.println(s.contains(Long.valueOf(2)));
```

or

```
System.out.println(s.contains(2L));
```

Comment: I'd rather type "2L" ('L' uppercase) instead of "2l", since 2l might look like twenty-one.

Comment: @MarlonBernardes Edited : `2l` changed to `2L`.

Answer (score 6):

When you say `s.contains(2)`, it searches for `2` which by default is an `int`, which gets boxed to `Integer`. But the object which you stored was `Long`. So, it returns `false`

Try using `s.contains(Long.valueOf(2))` instead.

Comment: Actually, the object stored was a `Long`, not a `long`. But +1 for getting the essence of the issue correct.

Comment: Oops. Just a typo. Thanks for notifying. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Hashset stores object of Long and not int/Integer.. You are trying  to get an Integer where int is boxed while an Object is required.